# JavaScript game enemy inheritance - Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create two types of enemies, the first is a robot that has 2 methods: sleep and patrol.

My second enemy is a flyingEnemy. The aim is to inherit the sleep method from the robot but amend the patrol method.

Can anyone show me how my flyingEnemy can inherit from robot whilst amending the patrol method?

Below is my code. When I create the flyingEnemy,  its patrol method overwrites the robot's patrol method and ALL enemies have the same behavior.

```
//-------------------------- ROBOT ENEMY 

var SuperSmash = SuperSmash || {};

SuperSmash.Enemy = function(game, x, y, key, velocity, tilemap, player) {
  Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, key);

  this.game = game;
  this.tilemap = tilemap;
  this.player = player;

};

SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.constructor = SuperSmash.Enemy;

SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.update = function() {
  this.currentstate();
};

SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.sleep = function() {
};

SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype.patrol = function() {
  var direction
  if (this.body.velocity.x > 0) {
    this.scale.setTo(1, 1);
    direction = 1;
  } else {
    this.scale.setTo(-1, 1);
    direction = -1;
  }

  var nextX = this.x + direction * (Math.abs(this.width) / 2 + 1);
  var nextY = this.bottom + 1;
  var nextTile = this.tilemap.getTileWorldXY(nextX, nextY, this.tilemap.tileWidth,   this.tilemap.tileHeight, 'collisionlayer');

  if (!nextTile) {
    this.body.velocity.x *= -1;
  }
};



    // --------------------------- FLYING ENEMY

    var SuperSmash = SuperSmash || {};

    SuperSmash.flyingEnemy = function(game, x, y, key, velocity, tilemap, player) {
      SuperSmash.Enemy.call(this, game, x, y, key);

      this.game = game;
      this.tilemap = tilemap;
      this.player = player;

      this.animations.add("fly", [0]);
    };

    SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype = Object.create(SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype);
    SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype.constructor = SuperSmash.flyingEnemy;

    SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.patrol = function() {
      "use strict";
       SuperSmash.game.physics.arcade.moveToObject(this, this.player, 200);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//Defining methods (Robot)
SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.sleep = function() {
  //Code
  console.log('Call sleep() from Robot');
};

SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.patrol = function() {
  //Code
  console.log('Call patrol() from Robot');
};

//In FlyingEnemy
SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype.sleep = function() {
   //Inheriting the method Sleep
   SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype.sleep(this);
   console.log('Call sleep() from flyingEnemy');
}

SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype.patrol = function() {
   //Override
   console.log('Call patrol() from flyingEnemy');
}
```

If the problem persists, it is probably due to this line (I'm not really sure):

`SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype = Object.create(SuperSmash.Enemy.prototype);`

If it continues the same it tries to do it with Sprite and it overwrites or it inherits the prototypes of the methods that you need in flyingEnemy, in this case they are only 2:

`SuperSmash.flyingEnemy.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);`